# To show the existence of $f,g\in\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{F})$ such that $f(x)\neq g(x) \forall x\in S\subseteq V$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. Show that, given any $\emptyset = S ⊆ V \backslash\{0\}$, there exist nonzero linear functionals $f$ and $g$ on $V$ such that, $∀x ∈ S$, $f(x) \neq g(x)$.

*I've tried several things here:*
First, I came up with a vague argument that requires some gap-filling. Consider two non-zero functionals $f,g\in\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{F})$ such that $f(x)=g(x)\neq 0$, for all $x\in S'\subseteq S$. We keep $f$ as it is, and construct a new functional $\alpha g$ from $g$ by multiplying by a suitable scalar $\alpha$. We do this as follows:
Let $y\in S'$, so $f(y) =  g(y) \neq 0$. Then $f(y) \neq \alpha g(y)$ for some choice of scalar $\alpha$. We change $g$ iteratively so that eventually we "cover" all points in $S'$, and end up with two functionals $f$ and $\alpha_0 g$, so that $f(x) \neq \alpha_0g(x)$ $\forall x\in S$.

I have assumed that $f(x) = g(x)\neq 0$ in several places, but it may be too much to ask that none of the functionals go to zero on any point in $S$. I believe this is what's to be shown anyway - that we can find such functionals! How do I do that?

Also, I tried an inductive argument since $V$ is finite-dimensional (on the dimension of $V$), but that didn't go anywhere.

I'd appreciate any hints, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction on $\dim V.$ If $\dim V=1$ then $V=\{av:a\in \mathbb F\}.$ Set $f(v)=1$ and $g(v)=1+1.$

Suppose the claim is true for all $(V,\mathbb F)$ such that $\dim V=n.$

Suppose now that $\dim V=n+1$ and consider $\mathscr S=\operatorname{span}\ S.$ If $\dim \mathscr S<n+1$ then there are functionals $f,g:\mathscr S\to \mathbb F$ such that $f\neq g$ on $S$. Extend these to $\tilde f,\tilde g$ on $V$ by defining them to be $0$ on $\mathscr S^{\perp}.$

If $\dim \mathscr S=n+1$ then choose a basis $\{v_1,\cdots, v_{n+1}\}$ for $\mathscr S.$ Each $s\in S$ can be written $s=a_1v_1+\cdots +a_{n+1}v_{n+1}.$ There are $f,g: \mathscr S'\to \mathbb F$ where  $\mathscr S'=\{s\in \mathscr S: a_{n+1}=0 \}$, that satisfy $f\neq g$ on $\mathscr S'\cap S.$ Extend $f$ by zero to all of $\mathscr S$ and $g$ to $\mathscr S$ by letting $g(v_{n+1})=1.$

The induction is complete and the claim follows.

Comment: Do you mean "each $s\in \operatorname{span}(S)$ can be written..."?

Comment: Well, $S\subseteq  \operatorname{span}(S)$ so each $s\in S$ can also be written as such. And I wanted to specify that the $s$ I chose belonged to $S$.